# MongoDb Connect to Replica Set Primary Issue C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I get back the name of the primary database? Lets say database3 was primary

Thanks

```
var connString = "mongodb://database1,database2,database3/?replicaSet=repl";
var client = new MongoClient(connString);
var server = client.GetServer().Instances.FirstOrDefault(server => server.IsPrimary);
var address = server.Address;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Why do you need to get the address of the Primary?

Comment: So that instead of having the primary address as a constant and let's say another server is set as the primary I will always have the proper address

Comment: I have added an answer. The primary server is not exposed in the MongoDB driver, but you can query it from MongoDB itself using `{isMaster:1}` and parsing the returned document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at the source code of the MongoDB driver, there is no straightforward way to get the name of the primary server from the driver itself. However, you can query server name in MOngoDB by executing `{isMaster:1}` using `RunCommand`. You can then parse the primary server from the returned JSON document. This approach works regardless if you are connected to the primary or secondary server.

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
var testDB = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");
var cmd = new BsonDocument("isMaster", "1");
var result = testDB.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(cmd);
var primaryServer = result.Where(x => x.Name == "primary").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You really should **not** handle connecting to the right server yourself. The MongoDB driver handles that for you.

Just specify all of your servers in the connections string and the driver will connect to one of them and get replica set's current state on its own. The driver will then direct write operations to the current primary. Read operations may be directed to the primary, or any other server, depending on the [**read preference**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/read-preference/) you specify.

You can read about forming replica set connection strings here: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Hi Dmytro thanks for the answer. I've edited my question above to exactly what I want. I just need the name of the primary server so I can pass this into another method

Comment: As Dmytro has explained it is bad practice to rely on the server name of the primary. A DBA would expect applications to automatically start using the new primary when the current primary is stepped down and the DBA will not be happy when you explicitly reference one server.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jaco for putting me on the right track I solved my problem by doing the following

```
public static string GetPrimaryDatabase()
{
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
    var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
    var database = server.GetDatabase("test");

    var cmd = new CommandDocument("isMaster", "1");
    var result = database.RunCommand(cmd);

        return result.Response.FirstOrDefault(
          response => response.ToString().Contains("primary")).Value.ToString();
}
```